# using has_secure_token with existing record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails trying to understand has_secure_token
I want token to be generated for all the existing and new groups and want to set expiry of two weeks and regenerate it every two weeks...

has_secure_token looked very good at a first sight, I am using it in my groups model to generate token as::

```
has_secure_token :group_token
```

it creates token on newly created groups and existing group has blank rows..

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup as you said `has_secure_token` has the issue that for existing entities the row keeps empty, that's because the secure token is generated during a `before_create` callback, for existing entities you can use something like this to get the token of any entity (old or new ones):

```rb
def get_group_token 
  self.regenerate_group_token if self.group_token.nil?
  self.group_token
end
```

define the function above inside your model class, of course, hope this helps you

The approach above trigger some `callbacks` and `validations`, in case you want to skip those this is another approach using the `update_column` method:

```rb
def get_group_token 
  self.update_column(:group_token, SecureRandom.base58(24)) if self.group_token.nil?
  self.group_token
end
```

hope helps!

docs for `update_column`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

Comment: thx for the edit suggestion is more readable in this way @zhisme 

Comment: WATCH OUT: although unlikely, it is possible to have collisions with the latter approach.